# Angularjs use $http post promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, angularjs-http

I try to use the promise respond from a $http.post, to get back the new ID of the record as integer and use it for the next $http.post.  My first code:

```
var streckenId;
var trackpunktId;

var getStreckeID = function () {
  $http.post(dbStrecke, {"ort": location, "distanz": km}).then(function (response) {
    streckenId = response.data;
    console.log("ID (then): " + streckenId); // return ID
  });
  return streckenId;
};

streckenId = getStreckeID();
console.log("StreckeID:" + streckenId); //return undefined
```

The last console.log still say that "streckenId" is undefined, so can anybody tell me what I do wrong? I hope anybody can help me

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/616717. It seems you do not fully understand an asynchronous flow.

Comment: Right, because you're still trying to get the value of your variable before the service has responded. Put the `console.log` in the `then()` function.

Comment: Try logging response.data first before assigning it to streckenId in first block of code , so that you can get some idea whats the http call is returning

Comment: It´s not a problem with the server, because if I use an api online tool, the server respond with the IDs.

Comment: @Pandiyan Cool: If I put the console.log into the then block, it respond with the id which I needed, but I also need to assign the value to use it outside the then block

Comment: `$http` is async.  You need to wait for the server to finish before proceeding to get the id's.  You need to do this:  `$http.post(step1).then(step2).catch(step1error);`